# How to query configurations from database in a custom MVC?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, configuration

I'm working on a multi-language website that its owner requires most configurations/options - that must be set first - to be stored in database, e.g.:

- default language
- default action
- default theme
- etc...

I'm confused where to query this config (as I'm still in the logic behind MVC approach).

1. Query the setting directly from a config file? (Is it ok to query a database from non-model file/class?)
2. Create a class file related to every set of configurations in the /core directory e.g.: language.php, theme.php and query database in these files?
3. Use **only** models to query these configurations?
4. If using models, should I access them directly from the config file or should I use controller to access them? (If I understand correctly, a controller is only a medium between views and models?).
5. Other suggestions ...?

The app root contains the following:

- backend

  - core
  - lib
  - models
  - config
  - views
  - controllers
  - helpers
  - handlers
- frontend

  - img
  - css
  - js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing that through a model and a controller, a little bit tricky though. But once it was done, the owner was pleased as that was more convenient for him to toggle defaults as desired from admincp without having to edit files to do that.